# Finding the Closure of a functional dependency

Tags: dependencies, relational-database, relation, functional-dependencies

I am trying to find the Closure of a functional dependency for the following relation schema and I seem to be having some trouble.

Would anyone be able to provide any input?

X is the relational schema for the functional dependencies:
R = (A, B, C, D, E):

{D→A, BA→C, C→E, E→DB}

Compute X<sup>+</sup> (the closure of X)

Answer (score 1):

*X<sup>+</sup> is a set of attributes that may be derived by applying Armstrong’s principles.*

X in X<sup>+</sup> refers to **one or more** attributes from our relation `R`.

So if X=A then
A<sup>+</sup> = {A}

If X=C then
C<sup>+</sup> = {A,B,C,D,E}

and if X=DA then
DA<sup>+</sup> = {A,D}

and so on. I hope you got the idea.